# Node.js: Created xlsx file that's stored in a variable, but uncertain how to save it

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, download, xlsx

I'm a newbie at Node.js, and I was trying out a package [xlr](https://github.com/madeagency/xlr) that supposedly allows me to export a data set to an Excel xlsx file.

I've completed all the steps to the point where I have an xlsx file stored in a variable, and I'm confident that all the steps that I've done up to that point are correct.

In the readme, that would be when:

```
const result = xlr(conf);
```

My question is: How would I save that file?

I've already tried writing the variable to a file, which didn't work, and the example provided by the xlr github readme uses Express, whereas I'm using the Node.js terminal to try to directly save it.

This is my first time doing anything with Node.js, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question, but I've spent a few hours trying to troubleshoot it and I haven't found any information relevant to it.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know anything about http, or express? Also, "download" wouldn't be the correct word in this case, you might mean simply "save" the generated file.

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely correct in that save would be the correct word.

I don't know anything about http or express, so I'm not sure how exactly to handle this without resorting to express, but based on a few minutes of googling, express is for web applications, and that's what not what I was going for

Comment: Right, so lets avoid http/express. So, XLR is returning it as a buffer, have you taken a look at https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: Actually `result` isn't a buffer, they use `new Buffer(result, 'binary')` to create a buffer of it

Comment: I've tried using "fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)" in the form of "fs.writeFile(temp.xlsx, result)", but the xlsx file that it created couldn't be opened b/c of errors

Comment: Oh, so would I need to create a buffer, and then using fs.writeFile to write it?

Comment: try `fs.writeFile("temp.xlsx",new Buffer(result,'binary'))` ?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: NP, seems like a pretty small/unmaintained library, might I suggest trying to find a more maintained library for generating excel files? https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx might allow you to generate excel files too, but it might also be more overwhelming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to avoid using http/express, you can save the file instead with

```
fs.writeFile("temp.xlsx", new Buffer(result, 'binary'), err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log("File written");
    }
});
```